# Mysql delete from Rows 20 onwards

Tags: mysql

I have an `SQL` statement,

```
select * from table1 where member_id='$member_id' order by date_time_modified desc;
```

which returns **48** rows, but I only want to the use the first **20** results.

How can I use a single `DELETE` statement to keep the first 20 rows and delete all of the rows after the 20th row (21 to 48).

Comment: Multiples ways, please see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` in your delete query, just change your sort order to delete the last rows and not the firsts

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE member_id='$member_id'
ORDER BY date_time_modified ASC
LIMIT 28
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete based on a list, you can use `IN`:

```
delete from your_table
where id in (value1, value2, ...);
```

If you need to delete based on the result of a query, you can also use `IN`:

```
delete from your_table
where id in (select aColumn from ...);
```

**(Notice that the subquery must return only one column)**

If you need to delete based on a range of values, either you use `BETWEEN` or you use inequalities:

```
delete from your_table
where id between bottom_value and top_value;
```

or

```
delete from your_table
where id >= a_value and id <= another_value;
```

Also, remember to add to the statement `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `ASC` or `DESC` as per your requirements.

You can play around and test out the statements you want to use:

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

[and Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are ordering by a date time descending, I guess you want to keep the newest 20 rows? If it is a one -time deletion order it in ascending order so that the older rows are given first and then limit it by (48-20) rows to delete:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE member_id='$member_id' ORDER BY date_time_modified ASC LIMIT 28
```